# Firebase Crashlytics with firebase-core gradle build with ProjectConfigurationException

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

I Try to add Crashlytics to projected I have been working on after trying on demo project. But gradle build failed with below error.

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:666)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:167)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getConfiguredBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:87)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$2.call(GradleBuildController.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:84)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
        ... 85 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 12"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
        at java_lang_Integer$valueOf$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.versionCompare(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:349)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor943.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1446)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:899)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
        at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$VersionRange.methodMissing(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor951.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:939)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1262)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
        at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$VersionRange.versionInRange(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:498)
        at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$VersionRange$versionInRange$4.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$_failOnVersionConflictForGroup_closure13$_closure15.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:410)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor938.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2040)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2025)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2078)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$165.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin$_failOnVersionConflictForGroup_closure13.doCall(GoogleServicesPlugin.groovy:399)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
        at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$CompositeSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:196)
        at org.gradle.internal.MutableActionSet.execute(MutableActionSet.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:204)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:198)
        at com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.addVariant(AppExtension.java:79)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:132)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:760)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:746)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:648)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
        ... 92 more
```

The Step I followed on sample project

1. Added crashlytics as instructed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)
2. Added firebase-core as instructed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

And everything works find from that point. But in this project I'm getting this error.

This is my gradle file code

**Module.app**

/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3"
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Project Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
   //
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           //
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Multi dex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'

    //Firebase core
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version is `2.9.1`:

```
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: when you add it android studio says 2.9.2 is available.